# Android intent creating new instance of object

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serializable

I'm passing a Serializable object using an Intent from Activity A to Activity B, but when I print the object.toString() method before putting the object into the intent in A and after retrieving it in B, I see that they are actually different instances.

Here's the problem. I have the fields of that object initialized in a different class and different thread, and by the time I put the object into an intent in Activity A, those fields aren't ready yet, but by the time I retrieve them they are ready. However, when I attempted to retrieve those fields in Activity B, I saw that they were empty because the retrieved object was a new instance.

How do I solve this problem? I don't know how to make the main thread wait until the object-initializing task is over (already tried thread.join()). I basically just have to send two ArrayLists from one activity to another, except when I'm sending them (i.e. putting them into an intent) they are empty but by the time they are being retrieved they are already populated.

Comment: it would be better if you could post some code.

Answer (score 0):

When serializing an object it's translated into a form that can later be used to create a semantically identical clone of the original object. This will of course be a different instance of the original object.

There are two scenarios I could think of:

- Your Activity B can run without having the information you're trying to send via Intent. In this case Activity B could register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and your thread, once finished, would broadcast the data via [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)
- Your Activity B can not run without that data and Activity A runs the code that generates that data e.g. in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and starts Activity B once the task has finished (that would be in the onPostExecute() method).